# What compound has the strongest optical rotation of polarised light?

Tags: stereochemistry, chirality, optical-properties

A question recently asked here whether compounds know to be chiral can have non-measurable optical rotations: [Are there chiral compounds that don't rotate plane-polarized light?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/103048/81).

Apparently they exist and the phenomenon is known as [cryptochirality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptochirality).

This prompted me to think of the opposite end of the spectrum of optical rotation. Which known compound shows the **largest** known optical rotation?

NB when I say "known compound" I mean something that has actually been synthesised in large enough quantities to be well characterised. So no theoretical-only compounds or esoteric systems.

Comment: One aspect which might make this tricky is that many publications are *awful* at using the correct units for specific rotation, meaning values are often ambiguous.

Comment: Various [helicenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicene) are said to have rather high specific optical rotations. What about switchable one from “low” rotation to high, is |\[α\]|=4680° enough? [:−)](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo0620213)

Comment: [Maximum observed optical rotation through a polarimeter](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32884/maximum-observed-optical-rotation-through-a-polarimeter) might come handy, if someone approches the question practically